# Linux CFS Volunteer Context Switches SCHED_OTHER SCHED_FIFO

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

I'm doing some Linux CFS analysis for my OS class and have an observation that I cannot explain.

For two otherwise identical processes, when they are executed with a SCHED_OTHER policy, I am seeing about 50% more voluntary context switches than when I exeucute them with a SCHED_FIFO or a SCHED_RR policy.

This wouldn't surprise me a bit for *involuntary* switches, since SCHED_OTHER has a much lower priority, so it has to give up the CPU.  But why would this be the case for *voluntary* switches. Why would SCHED_OTHER volunteer to give up the CPU more often than the real-time processes? It's an identical process, so it only volunteers to give up the CPU when it switches over to I/O, right? And I don't think that the choice of policy would affect the frequency of I/O attempts.

Any Linux people have an idea?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

First understand that the scheduling policies are nothing but the scheduling algorithms that are implemented in the kernel. So SCHED_FIFO, SCHED_RR, SCHED_OTHER are different algorithms in the kernel. SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR belong to the real time scheduling algorithms "class". SCHED_OTHER is nothing but the scheduling algorithm for normal processes in the system, more popularly known as the CFS(Completely Fair Scheduler) algorithm.

> SCHED_OTHER has a much lower priority

To be precise it doesn't have "much" lower priority but has "a" lower priority than the Real time scheduling class. There are three scheduling classes in the Linux Scheduler - Real-Time scheduling class, Normal Process scheduling class and Idle Tasks scheduling class. The priority levels are as follows:

1. Real Time Scheduling Class.
2. Normal Task Scheduling Class.
3. Idle Tasks Scheduling Class.

Tasks on the system belong to one of these classes. (Note that at any point in time a task can belong to only one scheduling class, although its class can be changed). The scheduler in Linux first checks whether there is a task in the real time class. If any, then it invokes the SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR algorithm, depending on what is configured on the system. If there are no real time tasks, then the scheduler checks for the normal tasks and invokes the CFS algorithm depending on whether there is any normal task ready to run. Also

Coming to the main question, why do see more context switches when you run the same process in two different scheduling classes. There are two cases:

1. Generally on a simple system, there are hardly any real time tasks and most task belong to normal task class. Thus, when you run that process in real time class, you will have all the processor to this process exclusively(since the real time scheduling class has a higher priority than normal task scheduling class, and there are no(/very few real) time task(s) to share the CPU with). When you run the same process in the normal task class, the process has to share the processor with various other processes, thus leading to more context switches.
2. Even if there are many real time tasks in the system, the nature of the real time scheduling algorithms in question, FIFO and RR, lead to lower context switches. In FIFO, a processor is not switched to other task until the current one completes and in RR there is a fixed interval(time-quanta) that is given to the processes. When you look at CFS, the timeslice that a process gets is proportional to the number of tasks in runqueue of the processor. It is a function of its weight and the total weight of the processor runqueue. I assume you are well versed with FIFO and RR since you are taking OS classes. For more information on CFS I will advice you to google it or if you are brave enough then go through its source code.

Hope the answer is complete :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. After reading this and my OP again, I realized that I neglected to mention an important fact, which is that the process that I am testing is an I/O bound process. Thus, by its nature, it's going to do a lot of voluntary context switching. However, I still can't come up with an answer to the question of why a normally scheduled task would *voluntarily* switch more often than would a real-time scheduled task. I get that such a process is going to voluntarily switch a lot, but why would I be seeing a difference between the policies? I thought that a voluntary switch had...

Comment: ...nothing to do with policy, but indicated that the process had gone over to I/O and didn't need the CPU at that point. Policy doesn't matter here, only what the process is doing at that moment, right? Am I right in thinking that *involuntary* switches can be explained by policy, but *voluntary* switches are attributable to the underlying program? Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that involuntary switches are explained by the policy, and voluntary switches are caused by process itself. But I maybe wrong, because this is what was taught to us for uniprocessor systems. I have my doubts about multiprocessor systems, I will  have to look at the source code for it. You've got me interested here. May I know what the program is that you are running (see if you can attach it to the OP) and how are you finding out the context switches, through getrusage() ? Is the program multi-threaded? Are you on a multiprocessor system?